# Script to delete facebook post

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

javascript or any method to delete post with given post_id from facebook account.Here is the post and i want to know how to click delete button programmatically [image]

Comment: You can use **iMacros** ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might only be able to delete content that was actually created by your application. Here is the documentation that is related to deleting objects from the graph: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/deleting/

> You can delete objects in the graph by issuing HTTP DELETE requests to the object URLs, i.e,

```
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/ID?access_token=... HTTP/1.1
```

> To support clients that do not support all HTTP methods (like JavaScript clients), you can alternatively issue a POST request to an object URL with the additional argument method=delete to override the HTTP method. For example, you can delete a comment by issuing a POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/COMMENT_ID?method=delete.

Comment: i know that, but i have to delete post not created by my application.plz help its urgent.